# android - how to prefill Edittext?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an app where I am storing the usernames. Once the user clicks on his username, it goes to the login screen. Can it be done that the username be already inputted in the login screen. , so that the user only has to enter his password? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the [`setText()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html#setText%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20android.widget.TextView.BufferType%29) function.

Answer (score 9):

you can use following code in xml:

```
android:text="<your text here>"
```

or

```
android:hint="<your text here>"
```

but there is more difference between those to `android:text` and  `android:hint`, first one sets the text and second one will display untill any text entered.